# Multiple calls to solr server for each request

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 7.5

In my search page, when I search for some word/query I have to make 28 calls to solr server out of which 4 are completely different calls, 12 are similar and remaining 12 are also similar but different to other 16 calls.

Now is it a problem when multiple users use the search at the same time because of number of calls to solr? Does it make the solr server non responding or crashed?

Please give your inputs.

Comment: That depends. 28 calls once a minute? No problem. 28 calls 3000 times each second .. well, that may be troublesome. Any optimization or solution would depend on what your calls are and ways to reduce the number of calls hitting Solr itself, and if/as necessary, introduce more nodes to handle your query load.

Comment: Thanks @MatsLindh